# Replace climbing sequence with its average

Tags: python, list

I have a random list like this

```
X = [0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 10, 15]
```

and need to find and replace every climbing sequence with its average.
In the end it should look like this:

```
X = [0, 6, 10, 15]       #the 0 and 1 to 0; and the 5,6,7 to 6
```

I tried to find the sequence by subtracting the second value from the first like this:

```
y = 0
z = []
while X[y +1] -X[y] == 1: 
            z.append(X[y])

            y = y +1
```

And now I dont know how to delete for example 5,6 and 7 and replace it with the average 6.

Comment: What do you mean, "delete ... 5, 6, 7"?  Your partial solution builds a new list; it doesn't remove anything from the original.

Comment: I see nowhere that you've attempted to take the mean of a sequence.

Comment: Not quite understand what is a climbing sequence. I can't find any result on google. Could you provide more details? Btw, average of 0 and 1 is 0.5. Even `int(0.5)` gives 0

Comment: With 'climbing sequence' you apparently mean 'climbing sequence in steps of exactly 1'. And when computing the average, you apparently want to round down. You should make that explicit.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.groupby` on the list with a key function that returns each item's difference with an incremental counter:

```
from itertools import groupby, count
from statistics import mean

X = [0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 10, 15]
c = count()
X = [int(mean(g)) for _, g in groupby(X, key=lambda i: i - next(c))]
```

`X` becomes:

```
[0, 6, 10, 15]
```

Comment: It's a nice, clean and perfectly usable solution. Also probably the solution that gets OP a failing grade for asking on StackOverflow if this is a CS 101 assignment :D

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate and group in the same list each climbing sequence for then taking the mean.

```
>>> res = [[x[0]]]
>>> for i in range(1, len(x)):
...     if x[i] == x[i-1] + 1:
...             res[-1].append(x[i])
...     else:
...             res.append([x[i]]
>>> res
[[0, 1], [5, 6, 7], [10], [15]]
>>> [int(sum(l)/len(l)) for l in res]
[0, 6, 10, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting technique: make a new list that's the difference of adjacent elements in the list:

```
diff = [X[i] - X[i-1] for i in range(1, len(X)) ]
```

There are more "Pythonic" ways to do this, but I want to make sure this is accessible to newer programmers.

You now have `diff` as

```
[1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 5]
```

Where you have a `1` in `diff`, you have a climbing pair in `X`.  Iterate through `diff` to find a sequence of `1` values.  Where you find this, take the `slice` of `X` that corresponds to the `1` values.  The middle element of that slice is your mean.

If the value is not `1`, then you simply take the corresponding element of `X`, as you've been doing.

`append` the identified values to `z`, and there's your desired result.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Not really to answer the question, which is a fairly basic CS 101 question that people should try to figure out themselves, but what I noticed about the nice answer of @blhsing was that it appeared fairly slow. I found that `mean()` is incredibly slow!

```
from itertools import groupby, count
from statistics import mean
from timeit import timeit


def generate_1step_seq1(xs):
    result = []
    n = 0
    while n < len(xs):
        # sequences with step of 1 only
        if not result or xs[n] == result[-1] + 1:
            result += [xs[n]]
        else:
            # int result, rounding down
            yield sum(result) // len(result)
            result = [xs[n]]
        n += 1
    if result:
        yield sum(result) // len(result)


def generate_1step_seq2(xs):
    c = count()
    return [int(sum(xs) // len(xs)) for xs in [list(g) for _, g in groupby(xs, key=lambda i: i - next(c))]]


def generate_1step_seq3(xs):
    c = count()
    return [int(mean(g)) for _, g in groupby(xs, key=lambda i: i - next(c))]


values = [0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 10, 15]

print(list(generate_1step_seq1(values)))
print(generate_1step_seq2(values))
print(generate_1step_seq3(values))

print(timeit(lambda: list(generate_1step_seq1(values)), number=10000))
print(timeit(lambda: list(generate_1step_seq2(values)), number=10000))
print(timeit(lambda: list(generate_1step_seq3(values)), number=10000))
```

Initially I figured that was probably due to the tiny list size, but even for large lists, `mean()` is horribly slow. Anyone happen to know why? It appears due to the very safe nature of `statistics` `_sum`, trying to avoid `float` rounding errors?